# Buffer: shape_Area=0

Tags: arcgis-pro, buffer, gps, area, intersect

I used the GPX to feature tool to add data points to my map. I draw buffers with a different radius around each point >10 m (some of them overlap). However, the column shape_Area is 0 for all the data points.
I have used the calculate geometry attribute and added the points as a CSV file but got the same result.